# Issue with SQLite query

Tags: sql, database

Problem Specification and Database Condition: There are 3 tables (**Highschooler**, **Friend** and **Likes**) in the database and Here is  database :

```
Highschooler
ID  name    grade
1510    Jordan  9
1689    Gabriel 9
1381    Tiffany 9
1709    Cassandra   9
1101    Haley   10
1782    Andrew  10
1468    Kris    10
1641    Brittany    10
1247    Alexis  11
1316    Austin  11
1911    Gabriel 11
1501    Jessica 11
1304    Jordan  12
1025    John    12
1934    Kyle    12
1661    Logan   12

Friend
ID1 ID2
1510    1381
1510    1689
1689    1709
1381    1247
1709    1247
1689    1782
1782    1468
1782    1316
1782    1304
1468    1101
1468    1641
1101    1641
1247    1911
1247    1501
1911    1501
1501    1934
1316    1934
1934    1304
1304    1661
1661    1025
1381    1510
1689    1510
1709    1689
1247    1381
1247    1709
1782    1689
1468    1782
1316    1782
1304    1782
1101    1468
1641    1468
1641    1101
1911    1247
1501    1247
1501    1911
1934    1501
1934    1316
1304    1934
1661    1304
1025    1661

Likes
ID1 ID2
1689    1709
1709    1689
1782    1709
1911    1247
1247    1468
1641    1468
1316    1304
1501    1934
1934    1501
1025    1101
```

Question is : `For every student who likes someone 2 or more grades younger than themselves, return that student's name and grade, and the name and grade of the student they like.`

My query is :

```
select HS11.name,HS11.grade,HS22.name,HS22.grade from
( select ID1,ID2 from Likes where ID1 in
(
select HS1.ID from Highschooler HS1, Highschooler HS2 
where HS1.ID<> HS2.ID and (HS1.grade - HS2.grade) >=2 
)
and ID2 in
(
select HS2.ID from Highschooler HS1, Highschooler HS2 
where HS1.ID<> HS2.ID and (HS1.grade - HS2.grade) >=2 
)
) as G, Highschooler HS11, Highschooler HS22
where HS11.ID=G.ID1 and HS22.ID = G.ID2
```

My query's output is :

```
Alexis 11 Kris 10
John 12 Haley 10
```

Expected output is:

```
John 12 Haley 10
```

So, I am getting 1 row extra which incorrect. Could anyone please point out what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Woah... How many subselects!!! :o Pity the DB Server...

Comment: Could you please suggest some better idea ? @Praveen Kumar

Comment: It does not work because what you do is the following: From the table of likes you select those pairs where there exists someone that is 2 years younger than the one in id1 and someone that is 2 years older than the one from id2. but there can be 4 people involved: There are 9th graders, hence Alexis' 11th grade is ok, and there are 12th graders, hence Kris' 10th grade is ok.

Comment: Also: It would be better to use select distinct in your "Where id1 in select DISTINCT..." because otherwise you generate unwanted replica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for

```
select a.name as liker, a.grade as liker_grade, c.name as likee, c.grade as likee_grade from
highschooler a inner join likes b on a.id = b.id1
left join highschooler c on b.id2 = c.id
where a.grade >= c.grade +2
```

and if the likes are always mutual (which usually is not the case, combine with itself and union all

```
select a.name as liker, a.grade as liker_grade, c.name as likee, c.grade as likee_grade from
highschooler a inner join likes b on a.id = b.id1
left join highschooler c on b.id2 = c.id
where a.grade >= c.grade +2
union all
select a.name as liker, a.grade as liker_grade, c.name as likee, c.grade as likee_grade from
highschooler a inner join likes b on a.id = b.id2
left join highschooler c on b.id1 = c.id
where a.grade >= c.grade +2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `SELECT` statement can be simplified by using `INNER JOIN`. Then you can have one `WHERE` clause that specifies the requirement:

```
SELECT HS1.name, HS1.grade, HS2.name, HS2.grade
FROM Likes
INNER JOIN Highschooler HS1
  ON Likes.ID1 = HS1.ID
INNER JOIN Highschooler HS2
  ON Likes.ID2 = HS2.ID
WHERE (HS1.grade - HS2.grade) >=2
```

In other words, instead of trying to find the IDs you need by using subqueries with convoluted requirements, you select one virtual table, and place requirements on it directly.

Answer (score 0):

If yes, then this should work

```
Select main.*
  from Highscooler main
       join Likes lk on main.ID = lk.ID1
       join Highscooler mate on mate.ID = lk.ID2
  where main.Grade >= mate.Grade+2
```

EDIT: Corrected the answer (I thought 'likes' is expressed using the 'friends' table). Also did not understand 'like' (I am not using FB ;-) )

Corrected again :  I am not good in reading text ...

Comment: Friend is bijective but the query is not working. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Uh... the requirement doesn't involve "Friend" at all.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. I corrected the query accordingly. Now it looks for all people who like at least persons

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   liker.ID AS LikerID,
         liker.Name AS LikerName,
         liker.Grade AS LikerGrade,
         liked.ID AS LikedID,
         liked.Name AS LikedName,
         liked.Grade AS LikedGrade
FROM     Likes
JOIN     HighSchooler Liker ON Likes.ID1 = Liker.ID
JOIN     HighSchooler Liked ON Likes.ID2 = Liked.ID
WHERE    2 <= (Liker.Grade - Liked.Grade)
```

Should get you close

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working. But, it would be great if you could point out the problem in my query as well.

Comment: That's probably not going to happen.  I don't make it a habit to delve deep into other people's insanity. :)

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your nice answer. I learned some good techniques from your query :-)

Comment: What is "berating the OP" ?

Comment: @Dan-o, whose answer is very good, is calling you or your code insane.  Berating is "Scolding or criticising (someone) angrily".

Comment: Richard is under the mistaken opinion that I am being mean to you.  But this comment section is not the place to hold conversations.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (sytax maybe wrong) and replace `select *` with the correct columns

```
select * from highschooler as me
left join on friend where me.id = friend.id1
left join on highschooler as f where f.id = freind.id2
where me.grade - f.grade >= 2
```

Comment: You are missing the restriction to only show persons which have at least 2 likes.